# Format a string in blocks of 3 digits

Tags: javascript, regex, string

How would I go about reformating a string into **blocks of 3 digits** separated by dash (-) in JavaScript?

ex:

```
let myString = "00  64 33 3-44-23 982-  23-1-0"
```

produce desired output as:

```
myString = "006-433-344-239-822-310"
```

Comment: Indeed @torazaburo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With regex:

```
("00  64 33 3-44-23 982-  23-1-0").replace(/\D/g,"").replace(/(\d{3})(?!$)/g,'$1-')
```

Explanation:

- `\D` - remove all non numeric characters
- `(\d{3})(?!$)`

  - `(\d{3})` - match 3 numbers
  - `(?!$)` - but not the last 3

---

To turn `0 - 22 1985--324` into `022-198-53-24`:

```
("0 - 22 1985--324")
  .replace(/\D/g,"")                 // strip numbers
  .replace(                          // do specific format
    /^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/g,
    '$1-$2-$3-$4'
  )
```

Comment: Thank you Isaac. Regex is a new territory for me. What would be the equivalent regex for the following: 0 - 22 1985--324 resulting in 022-198-53-24. Do I have to compare the string with a % 3?

Comment: Id do something different for that, but for that exact format I shall amend my answer

Comment: Thank you. Basically, I need case 1 to be exactly like your first solution, however in the event of a string, not having enough groups of 3. The last two blocks should default to blocks of two digits if necessary. That's why I wonder If I need an if else looking for string % 3 = 0;

Answer (score 5):

From what you've said in the comments I believe you want groups of 3 where possible and groups of 2 at the end if there aren't enough numbers. I believe this will do it:

```js
[
    '1-2 3   45---67  890',
    '12345678901',
    '123456789012',
    '1234567890123',
    '12345678901234',
    '1',
    '12',
    '123',
    '1234',
    '12345',
    '123456',
    '1234567'
].forEach(function(str) {
    console.log(str.replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/(\d\d\d?)(?=\d\d)/g, '$1-'));
});
```

The `/\D/g` removes all the non-digits. The capture group `(\d\d\d?)` will attempt to grab 3 digits if it can (RegExps are greedy so they grab as much as possible) but if it can't grab 3 digits that `?` makes the third digit optional. The lookahead `(?=\d\d)` requires there to be at least 2 more digits after the initial capture. The result of this is that if there are 5 or more digits remaining in the string this will result in 3 digits being included in the capture but if there are only 4 remaining it will apply the `?` to grab just 2 digits.

When making multiple matches using the `g` flag the string is consumed from start to finish in one run. Each time it makes a match it doesn't go back to the start again, it just carries on. This means that matches can never overlap. Lookaheads provides a way to check what's coming up next without including it in the match, so that you can effectively rewind.

The key to understanding this RegExp is the observation that wherever we insert a `-` in the result there must always be at least 2 more digits after it. In English it translates as *'grab 3 digits if we can (or 2 if we can't) so long as there are 2 more digits yet to come'*.

Comment: That's precisely right. thank you very much @skirtle. I'll spend some time studying your solution. I accepted Isaac answer so I don't get in trouble with moderators red flagging my initial question. Thanks Again!

Comment: @tonkihonks13 Not a problem, Isaac's solution works well for the original question. I was in two minds about whether to post my solution as a comment on his. In the end I decided I needed my own answer to include the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

First you can use 'replace' to remove any non-digit characters with regex.

```
let myString = "00  64 33 3-44-23 982-  23-1-0"
myString = myString.replace(/\D/g, "")

// "006433344239822310"
```

Secondly, 'match' any digits (0-9) between 1 and 3 times. The match function conveniently returns an array with an item for each match.

```
myString = myString.match(/\d{1,3}/g)

// [006,433,344,239,822,310]
```

Lastly, join the array using "-" as the separator.

```
myString = myString.join("-");

// 006-433-344-239-822-310
```

And if you would like to chain each step together..

```
myString = myString.replace(/\D/g, "").match(/\d{1,3}/g).join("-");
```

Note that if the string has any leftover digits, they will be left in their own block on the end of the string. This is due to the 1-3 match.

For example..

```
"00  64 33 3-44-23 982-  23-1-0  24" // before - with 2 extra digits
"006-433-344-239-822-310-24" // after - the extra digits are maintained
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a non-regexp solution:

```
joinGroups(joinDigits(partition3(extract(string))))
```

`joinGroups` is just

```
// Join groups of digits with a hyphen.
const joinGroups = a => a.join('-');
```

`joinDigits` is easy enough too:

```
// Join elements of subarrays together into strings.
const joinDigits = groups = groups.map(group => group.join(''));
```

`extract` is easy too:

```
// Extract all digits from a string and return as array.
const extract = input => input.match(/\d/g);
```

`partition3` is a little harder. There are many samples here on SO and elsewhere. See the implementation in the snippet for one idea.

```js
const joinGroups = a => a.join('-');
const joinDigits = groups => groups.map(group => group.join(''));
const extract = input => input.match(/\d/g);
const partition = n => 
  a => Array.from(
    {length: Math.floor((a.length - 1) / n) + 1}, 
    (_, i) => a.slice(i * n, (i + 1) * n));

const partition3 = partition(3);

const data = "00  64 33 3-44-23 982-  23-1-0";

console.log(joinGroups(joinDigits(partition3(extract(data)))));
```